# Making multiple sentences out of 5 words

Tags: word, word-property, english

Given below are four or five letter english words. Total 5.

> Using all the 5 words exactly once, can you make at least 8
> grammatically correct english sentences?

M___

C___

T___

B___

N___

You can use proper nouns and punctuation marks. Every sentence will have all (those) five words. no cutting or joining of words. All words must be in MW dictionary.

Example:

C___ m___ t___ b___ n___ .

Comment: What a [Rorschach test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rorschach_test), to be enjoyed.

Comment: I agree. It's almost random words, but the choice is important.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a general strategy to get 24 sentences...

> Choose M___, B___, and N___ to be words that are both verbs and uncountable nouns. Then, insert them freely into the three blanks in the following four sentences: "____ could ____ that ____", "Could ____ ____ that ____?", "That ____ could ____ ____", and "Could that ____ ____ ____?"

...together with one specific implementation. (For a few randomly chosen sentences, I've included a paraphrasing to help you parse them.)

> Merit could bias that need. (That sense of necessity could be biased by what is more worthy.)
>  Merit could need that bias. (It's possible that virtue needs us to be biased in that way.)
>  Bias could need that merit.
>  Bias could merit that need.
>  Need could merit that bias. (An obligation we have could be cause for being biased like that.)
>  Need could bias that merit.
>  Could merit bias that need?
>  Could merit need that bias?
>  Could bias need that merit?
>  Could bias merit that need? (Is it the case that our biased outlooks are cause for us to need that unspecified thing?)
>  Could need merit that bias?
>  Could need bias that merit?
>  That merit could bias need.
>  That merit could need bias.
>  That bias could need merit.
>  That bias could merit need.
>  That need could merit bias.
>  That need could bias merit. (That necessity could bias our judgement of what is virtuous.)
>  Could that merit bias need?
>  Could that merit need bias?
>  Could that bias need merit? (Is it possible that that particular biased point of view needs to be honored?)
>  Could that bias merit need?
>  Could that need merit bias?
>  Could that need bias merit?

Answer (score 3):

> A few somewhat nonsensical questions:
>  Can't Mary's toys blast noise?
>  Can't Mary's noise blast toys?
>  Can't toys blast Mary's noise?
>  Can't noise blast Mary's toys?
>  Mary's toys can't blast noise?
>  Mary's noise can't blast toys?
>  Toys can't blast Mary's noise?

> And, the finale: Noise can't blast Mary's toys?

I feel like this should be sufficient. :)

Comment: The words do need to be 4 or 5 letters long though, one of your words doesn't fit this requirement sadly... (Also don't forget to spoiler your answer!)

Comment: So with this new answer you lost "M" word and added an extra T word. We need all 5 listed words in each senntence. Also we need at least 8 sentences.

Comment: AUGH! Proper nouns ARE allowed, correct?

Comment: rot13(Ercynpr lbhe "gurve" jvgu "zber" naq vg'yy jbex.  Nyfb, vs pbagenpgvbaf pbhag nf wbvavat jbeqf, lbh pbhyq hfr "pbhyq" vafgrnq bs "pna'g".)

Comment: Lrf, V xabj. Ohg gurl nyybjrq pbagenpgvbaf. Fb V guvax V'z svar. Vg jbhyq or n fznyy rqvg naljnlf.

Answer (score 3):

You could use those five words:

> **might Chaos tarts break Norse**
>  Here "Chaos" is used as a brand of sorts.
>  Here is an example with another (fictive) person who created a famous pie recipe. Zheng created Zheng pies. Zheng pies were created by Zheng.

In use:

> Might Chaos tarts break Norse?
>  Might Chaos Norse break tarts?
>  Might Norse tarts break Chaos?
>  Might Chaos Norse tarts break?
>  Might Norse Chaos tarts break?
>  Might Norse Chaos break tarts?
>  Might tarts break Chaos Norse?
>  Might tarts break Norse Chaos?
>  Norse Chaos might break tarts.
>  Norse tarts might break Chaos.
>  Norse Chaos tarts might break.
>  Chaos Norse tarts might break.
>  Chaos tarts might break Norse.
>  Chaos Norse might break tarts.
>  Tarts might break Chaos Norse.
>  Tarts might break Norse Chaos.
>  There might be more sentences I missed.
>  Also I would not be surprised if any of those sentences were used in a place like [RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: insane amount. you'll probably get the tick. :)